# Select max date

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains 3 columns:

- `id (int)`
- `name (String)`
- `date_created (Date)`

How can I select last name added to the database based on the `date_created` column?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: How do you want to handle ties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL-SERVER:

```
SELECT TOP 1 name
FROM dbo.TableName
ORDER BY date_created DESC
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT name
FROM dbo.TableName
ORDER BY date_created DESC
Limit 1
```

You can use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` in T-SQL if you want to include all when multiple rows have the same highest `date_created` value.  On MySQL you need to use  sub-queries. [**Here's**](http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/TOP-n-WITH-TIES-in-MySQL) an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name FROM table
WHERE date_created  = (SELECT MAX(date_created) FROM table)
```

Comment: This will return N records matching that criteria --assuming data_created is NOT a timestamp.

Comment: That I know, however, your solution wouldn't return last name added --it would return all last names added on that date. e.g. if table had 1k records added on `13/01/2013`, then your solution would return all 1k records NOT last one added...

Comment: Wow, Then, how do you think OP not thought about it, and what of these names does he want?

Comment: OP did, that's the reason he pick on @tim-schmelter's solution. Your solution missed one tiny detail --TOP for an MS-SQL implementation or LIMIT for a MySQL implementation

Comment: And what about Oracle? Under the OP there are question about RDBMS are used. Then i give solution in SQL standard.

Comment: You're right, OP request is clearly not RDBMS agnostic --Oracle solution has already been provided by @gordon-linoff. I was merely pointing out a flaw in your proposed solution seeing that OP's `date_created` field is of type `Date`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an autoincrementing (identity in SQL Server) id, then you can use that instead:

```
select name
form table
order by id desc
limit 1
```

Of course, `limit 1` depends on the database.  It would be `select top 1` in SQL Server, `where rownum = 1` in Oracle, and `fetch first 1 row` in db2.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a subquery:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.date_created
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select max(date_created) MaxDate
  from yourtable
) t2
  on t1.date_created = t2.maxdate
```

This will return all records that have the `max(created_date)`